# Converting Strings to Symbols and Integers inside my hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

I made it this far, but don't know where to add the .to_i and the .to_sym methods since I'm assuming I put them in the wrong place. Can someone help me out? When I test the code out it says "undefined method `to_sym=' for nil:NilClass"

```
movies = { 
  spiderman: 3,
  superman: 4,
  batman: 5
}

puts "what movie do you like?"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when 'add'
puts "What movie do you want to add?"
title.to_sym = gets.chomp
puts "what is the rating of that movie?"
rating.to_i = gets.chomp
movies[title]=rating
puts "Added!"

when 'update'
    puts "What movie would you like to update?"
    title = gets.chomp
    puts "Updated!"
when 'display'
    movies.each do |movies, ratings|
    puts "#{movies}: #{ratings}"
    end

    puts "Movies!"
when 'delete'
    puts "What movie would you like to delete from the list?"
    title = gets.chomp
    puts "Deleted!"

else 
    puts "Error!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides `[]=`, there is no method of the form `foo=`, or `to_sym=`, as in your code, in plain Ruby. If you want to get a user input as a symbol, you can do:

```
title = gets.chomp.to_sym
```

If you want to get an integer, you can do:

```
rating = gets.to_i
```

I don't know why you had `chomp` in the latter case.

Comment: Ok. That worked. I get it now. I just got so used to adding chomp onto the end of gets. Thanks though